# How to test for not null value result in dbunit

Tags: java, xml, dataset, dbunit

To test for null the dataset reference can be set as

```
<dataset>
    <table name="order_test">
        <column>foreignId</column>
        ...
        <row>
            <null/>
        ...
       </row>
...
```

How would it be possible to pass the assertion when the result gives a random value back? I have tried `<notnull/>` or `<value/>` but no juice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing the query I use so if the column is not null 
e.g.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN foreignId IS NOT NULL THEN 'foreignId' ELSE foreignId END
FROM table
```

then I have a specific value to set in dataset reference:

```
<dataset>
    <table name="order_test">
        <column>foreignId</column>
        ...
        <row>
            <value>foreignId<value/>
        ...
       </row>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can try to use:

```
<dataset>
    <table name="order_test">
        <column>foreignId</column>
        ...
        <row>
             <null description="foreignId"/>
        ...
       </row>
```

...

Answer (score -1):

For random values like this (e.g. timestamps), usually ignore the column in the expected result set.  See [DefaultColumnFilter](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/dbunit/dataset/filter/DefaultColumnFilter.html).

For example:

```
String[] excludeColumns = {"col1", "col2"};
ITable filteredTable = DefaultColumnFilter.excludedColumnsTable(table, excludeColumns);
```